# Pass an ArrayList as parameter to StoredProcedure from a class

Tags: java, stored-procedures

How to pass an `ArrayList` as parameter to `StoredProcedure` from a Java class?

I have a method from which database `StoredProcedure` is called like shown in below code:

```
 public void insertFileDownload(ArrayList<String> spareaList, ArrayList<String> spcollrtList, ArrayList<String> spmaintRtList, ArrayList<String> spenfRtList) {


 if (spareaList != null) {
            for (String a : spareaList) {//for Areas
                Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                param.put("areaName", a);
                param.put("collroutesName", null);
                param.put("maintrtsName", null);
                param.put("enfrtsName", null);

                genericDao.sqlQueryWithParameters(" {call sp_addMeterJob(:areaName,:collroutesName,:maintrtsName,:enfrtsName) }", param);
            }

        } else if (spcollrtList != null) {//for CollectionRoutes

            for (String cllRt : spcollrtList) {
                Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                param.put("areaName", null);
                param.put("collroutesName", cllRt);
                param.put("maintrtsName", null);
                param.put("enfrtsName", null);                            

                genericDao.sqlQueryWithParameters(" {call sp_addMeterJob(:areaName,:collroutesName,:maintrtsName,:enfrtsName) }", param);
            }

..........
```

At present I am using if else conditions 4 times to check for each incoming array list parameter to set the values as parameters to stored procedures.

Is there any other better approach avoid many if else blocks?

Comment: maybe you can use overriding and to change the logic in the code a little

Comment: Add your SQL stored procedure to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not map the array in an XML file and pass it as the parameter (varchar)? That way you don't need to check for nulls in java. Then on the SP you retrieve it mapping it back to a table and it automatically puts nulls if a parameter is null or is missing from the xml:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessArrayXML] @xml varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @xmlHandler int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlHandler OUTPUT, @xml

select * into #xmlBorrar
from openxml(@xmlHandler,'param') 
WITH (areaName varchar(50) '@areaName',
  collroutesName varchar(50) '@collroutesName',
  maintrtsName varchar(50) '@maintrtsName',
  enfrtsName varchar(50) '@enfrtsName')

--DOSOMETHING
select * from #xmlBorrar

end
```

If you call it with:

```
exec [ProcessArrayXML]  
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><param areaName = "1234" maintrtsName="1030" enfrtsName="1142" collroutesName="1204" />'
```

you've get a table with the parameters as columns, but if you leave one of the params out of the xml the column fills with null, for example...

```
exec [ProcessArrayXML]  
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><param collroutesName="1204" />'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clean up some of the boiler plate in your code, you should try something like this:

```
public void insertFileDownload(ArrayList<String> spareaList, 
  ArrayList<String> spcollrtList, ArrayList<String> spmaintRtList, ArrayList<String> spenfRtList) {
  if (!processList(spareaList, "areaName"))
    if (!processList(spcollrtList, "collroutesName"))
      if (!processList(spmaintRtList, "maintrtsName"))
        processList(spenfRtList, "enfrtsName");
}

private boolean processList(ArrayList<String> list, String mapKey) {
  boolean processed = false;
  if (list != null){
    processed = true;
    for (String a : list) {
      Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      param.put(mapKey, a);
      genericDao.sqlQueryWithParameters(" {call sp_addMeterJob(:areaName,:collroutesName,:maintrtsName,:enfrtsName) }", param);
    }      
  }
  return processed;
}
```

You don't need to add the explicit `null` key/values to the `Map` because any key not present in the `Map` will evaluate to `null` anyway if you call `get` for it.  If you really need those explicit `null` key/values in the `Map`, let me know and I will tweak the code a bit.